# JQuery UI radio value not changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button

My problem is the same than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565187/radio-button-selection-not-changing-value-with-jquery).

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" id="banana" value="Banana" checked="true" />
<input type="radio" name="test" id="cherry" value="Cherry" />
```

And the javascript:

```
$('[type="radio"]').buttonset();
```

When I click the 'Cherry' button, JQuery UI changes the view correctly. However, `$('[name="test"]').val();` returns "Banana"...

Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem I called `$('[name="test"]:checked').val();` and it seems to work.

If you want to detect a change of the radio button, do not call `$('[name="test"]').click()` but `$('[name="test"]').change()`.

I hope this will help people.

Comment: Watch out for webkit-based browsers, which historically have not fired change events on radio buttons, with the workaround being to capture the click event instead.

Comment: Actually this solution works either on Firefox and Chrome whereas firing the click event does not seem to work on Firefox (I didn't test it on Chrome). Am I wrong?